# How to use SCIP in ORTOOLS for MILP [python]

Tags: python, optimization, scip, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I have recently started with Ortools for a MILP problem.

I have tried CBC, but it is not providing global optimal solutions, only local (it seems to have a bug as reported in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/WYZrd-B7Esc)

I am trying SCIP (as suggested in some articles) by installing http://scip.zib.de/ and using the following command (python)

```
solver = pywraplp.Solver('L1', pywraplp.Solver.SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
```

However, I have received the following error message:

```
type object 'Solver' has no attribute 'SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING'
```

It looks like I have to inform Ortools I have this solver installed on my computer.

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recompile from sources.

Which platform are you on (OS, version, compiler) ?

Comment: OK, download the win64 build binaries, add the path to it as WINDOWS_SCIP_DIR in the Makefile.local, copy the scip dll on the PATH, then tools\make clean; tools\make python (you need ortools for that). and please read https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/python/source_windows before.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the follow code:

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
class Mode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Mode()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).